# What happens if we provide lower than specified VPP voltage for an OLED display?

Tags: display, oled

I came across these cheap 1.3" OLED displays (the bare display) based on the [SH1107](https://m5stack.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/resource/docs/datasheet/unit/oled/SH1107Datasheet.pdf) controller. I bought a few items and when I took a look at their ready-made modules I noticed a relatively complex board compared to the famous SSD1306 versions which I had experience with.

Here is the display:

[image: SH1107 OLED 1.3 display]

After a quick look at one of the module schematics, it seems these controllers lack an internal charge pump (I'm not sure about it though) and need an external voltage of 7.0V~16.5V for Vpp pin, whereas SSD1306 controllers have a charge pump with two capacitor pins provided for that circuitry.

Here is a schematic from [this website](https://botland.store/unit-extension-modules/19770-oled-display-13-128x64px-expansion-module-unit-for-m5stack-development-modules-6972934173034.html):

[image: SH1107 1.3 OLED schematic]

Since I use these displays mainly for portable devices, I don't like to use a dedicated boost converter just for an OLED so I keep them just for >9V supply devices.

1. I think it's possible for 9V batteries to provide the voltage. What happens if the battery drops to 8V or 7V over time?
2. What is the main difference if we apply 5V which is lower, or 7V~16V which is the same as given in the datasheet?

Comment: Then probably the screen won't work right. Actual damage is unlikely. Maybe just get one and try it!

Comment: by the way a charge pump is easier than a boost converter - depending on the current requirements, you might be able to get away with two capacitors, two diodes, and a microcontroller pin that toggles every so often

Comment: @user253751 Like a [Dickson charge pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier#Dickson_charge_pump)?

Comment: yes and you only need one pumping stage to get from 5V up to 10V

Answer (score 1):

> the brightness of the screen and the value depends on the resistance of Rref and Vpp:

I presume the brightness is linear with Vpp only in range, so below the limits, the display might be below the threshold to operate the pixel col/row drivers and suffer from low contrast or no display.

Lower than 15V for Vpp requires a smaller Rref resistor.

The lower intensity could be your battery State of Charge (SoC) indicator and also draw less current or simply hard to see/read.

The internal DCDC converter requires an external FET and passives for voltage scaling and current sensing/filtering to regulate Vpp.